# How to structure an if exists query to produce an error message

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a procedure which I am using to insert new columns into a table, and I have done an `IF` statement to basically say that if the date entered is before current date or not at least 30 days in the future then throw an error, now I want to create an `IF` statement that will only insert a new column if one of the rows exists... there are only three possible  courses that are in the table so the procedure asks for a course code and a date, can someone push me in the right direction for how to structure my IF statement to give an error when one of the three codes are not entered?

I don't know what keywords to use.

Here is my `IF` statement for the date checking:

```
IF (give_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) OR (give_date <= CURDATE()) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Enter A Date Over One Month';
ELSEIF (WEEKDAY(give_date) = 5 )THEN SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(give_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY);
ELSEIF (WEEKDAY(give_date) = 6 )THEN SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(give_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
ELSE SET loop_date = give_date;
END IF;
```

I am trying to do something like this...

```
    IF (new_code, EXISTS IN (module (course_code)) THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again';
    END IF;
```

Also tried doing this but getting an error saying the subquery returns more than one row...

```
IF give_code != ( SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = ('WSD' OR 'DDM' OR 'NSF'))THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; END IF;
```

Comment: Query should be like `IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_name WHERE conditionl) THEN `

Comment: I have tried the following but getting an error saying my syntax is wrong                       ```IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code LIKE ('WSD', 'DDM', 'NSF'))THEN 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again';
    END IF;```

Comment: replace `like` with `IN`

Comment: Trying this one but getting an error saying the subquery is returning more than one row  ``` IF give_code != ( SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = ('WSD' OR 'DDM' OR 'NSF'))THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; END IF; ```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing it like this:

```
IF give_code NOT IN ( SELECT course_code FROM module WHERE course_code = ('WSD' OR 'DDM' OR 'NSF'))THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you?

```sql
IF ( SELECT count(*) FROM module WHERE course_code in ('WSD','DDM','NSF')) > 0 
THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; 
END IF;
```

Comment: I need to to work differently, there are currently only 3 courses but if another one was to be added then it would break, I need to not hard code the courses but have them be read dynamically.

Comment: In that case, do you store list courses in a different table? or it's the procedure's input?